# Need help in converting SQL query to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

I am new to the world of LINQ and hence I am stuck at converting one sql query to LINQ.
 My SQL query is:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT PAYER) as count, 
       PPD_COL FROM BL_REV 
where BL_NO_UID = 1084 
GROUP BY PPD_COL
```

The desired output is:

```
 Count   PPD_COL
  12       P
  20       C
```

I have written something like below in LINQ:

```
 var PayerCount = from a in LstBlRev where a.DelFlg == "N"
                  group a by new { a.PpdCol} into grouping
                  select new
                  {
                      Count = grouping.First().PayerCustCode.Distinct().Count(),
                      PPdCol = (grouping.Key.PpdCol == "P") ? "Prepaid" : "Collect"
                  };
```

But it is not giving me the desired output. The count is returned same for `PPD_COL` value P & C. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `groupby` as following. in the `group` group only the property you need and then in thr `by` no need to create an anonymous object - just the one property you are grouping by.

```
var PayerCount = from a in LstBlRev 
                 where a.DelFlg == "N"
                 group a.PayerCustCode by a.PpdCol into grouping
                 select new
                 {
                     Count = grouping.Distinct().Count(),
                     PPdCol = grouping.Key == "P" ? "Prepaid" : "Collect"
                 };
```